# Best way to do a function in Laravel to calculate age of User?

Tags: laravel, models

I have the model "User" with the birthday data. I know how calculate the age using this birthday, but my doubt is what is the best way to create a function to calculate it when i'm working with a user register. I want to do anything like thiis:

```
$user = User::find(i)->get();
 echo $user->age();
```

I tried to create a static function inside User.php (model) but it need to receive the user as parameter.

Thanks

Comment: Don't make the function static.

Comment: @nhaarman: can you explain why not static?

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `get()` after `find()`, and don't make it static:

```php
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function age()
    {
        // return the user's age
    }

}
```

```php
$age = User::find(1)->age();
```

Comment: It is much more easier than I thought. Thank you very much! I'm newbie in webdevelopment. To know user birthday I just need to use $this->birthday inside function. Simple and easy!